# What is the area of the shaded region?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

The area of the square is 16 sq. units. A semicircle is inscribed on a side of the square with its diameter being that side of the square. An equilateral triangle rests with its base, on the opposite side of the square. Find the intersection area of the semicircle and the equilateral triangle.[image]

Comment: This is better suited for math SE.

Comment: It doesn't even look like a square...

Comment: All I can say is that by letting $A_c$ being the area of the circle and $A_t$ being the area of the triangle, I can gather that $$A_c=\pi\times 4^2\div 2 = \pi \times 16\div 2 = 8\pi$$ Since if the square has area $16$, then the side lengths must be $4$. Then we divide by $2$ because it is a semi-circle. And now, $$A_t = 4\times \frac 42\sqrt{3} = 4\times 2\sqrt{3}=8\sqrt{3}$$ Since the height of the triangle is (side length $\times \sqrt{3}\div 2$) with side length being equal to $4$ as the triangle is equilateral, so the base is equal to the rest of its sides.

Comment: Just saying, you should include your attempt(s)...

Comment: @user477343 I don't think so it's appropriate to include one's attempt on puzzling SE. Even though it's more like a mathematical problem, OP has posted it as a mathematical puzzle.

Comment: @LaschetJain ah yes, I see. Sorry about that — too much *Math.SE*. (That rhymes.)

Comment: @LaschetJain If setting a puzzle as a challenge, when you know the answer, of course you wouldn't include steps of the solution in the question. But if you're looking for help on a puzzle you want to solve but are stuck on, you'd want to include information on what you've tried and where you're stuck—so you get an answer that helps you get unstuck, instead of having someone just solve it for you. So showing one's attempts would be just fine, and would help avoid looking like a "do my homework please" question. As this stands, it looks like the latter ...

Comment: @Rubio I agree, OP seems somewhat like a do my homework guy. I still would argue that providing one's is not the best approach for Puzzling SE. You could release a hint a day later or something but I really would hate if someone biased me about the approach to the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is brute-force. Just leaving it here in case you don't get any other answers.

Let side of square be $a$.

I'm assuming $O$ is the centre of the semi-circle. Also, a line joining vertex $E$ of the equilateral triangle and point $O$ is perpendicular to $BC$. Let that perpendicular intersect the red region at point $O'$. Also let $EB$ and $EC$ intersect the semicircle at $B'$ and $C'$ respectively.

The distance EO is $a - \sqrt{3}a/2$ [height of square - height of eq. triangle]. Also, the distance $EO'$ is $a/2-length(EO)$ which is $\sqrt{3}a/2 - a/2$.

Now construct a triangle $EB'C'$. By symmetry, $EB' = EC'$. Also, the angle $B'EC' = 60^\circ$. Which means the constructed triangle is equilateral. Let height of this equilateral triangle be $h$. I'll show it's calculation later.

Following is the method to calculate area of region $R$ left by removing triangle $EB'C'$ from red region.

The area of the region $R$ can be found out by considering sector $OB'C'$. This sector belongs to the semi-circle. We can calculate the area of the triangle $OB'C'$ since $OB' = a/2$ and $OC' = a/2$ and $B'C' = (2/\sqrt{3})h$. [Since $B'C'$ is side of equilateral triangle $EB'C'$ and $h$ is it's height.]

Since we've got all sides of the triangle, we can calculate the area of the sector $OB'C'$ by applying co-sine rule to find the angle $B'OC'$. Once this area is calculated, subtract it from the area of the triangle $OB'C'$ to get area of region $R$.

To calculate $h$, we first need to find out the length of $EO' - h$: Let's call this $l$. $l$ is equal to radius of semi-circle minus height of $OB'C'$. Find the height in terms of $a$ and $h$ and later solve the the quadratic equation $(EO' - h)^2 = l^2$ for $h$. One root is positive and other is negative. Reject the negative one.

Use the fact $a = 4$ to get a numeric result.